# JQuery: Twitter Typeahead function for no match

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to assign a product id to a hidden html form field. This works great when there's a match:

```
$('.products_tt .typeahead').typeahead
    name: 'products_tt',
    prefetch: 
        url: '/products.json',
        ttl: 60 * 5e3
    template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan

$('.products_tt .typeahead').on "typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", (e,datum) ->
    $('#disk_file_product_id').val(datum.id)
```

I clear the hidden field when the input field is left blank:

```
$('.products_tt .typeahead').blur ->
    if $(this).val().length == 0
        $('#disk_file_product_id').val("")
```

But I also need to clear the hidden field when text has been entered in the input field but there's NO match.

My Java/Coffeescript skills are weak so not sure how to do this?!?

Answer (score 5):

One of the following should work:

1) Hook into your input field's `change` event first, and clear `#disk_file_product_id` there. Your `typeahead` events will later set this again if there was a selection. This also saves your the `blur` callback.

```
$('.products_tt .typeahead').change ->
    $('#disk_file_product_id').val("")
```

2) Clear `#disk_file_product_id` in the `opened` and `closed` events, instead of in the field's `change` event. I like this less.

```
$('.products_tt .typeahead').on "typeahead:opened typeahead:closed" ->
    $('#disk_file_product_id').val("")
```

Comment: Thanks, #1 appears to do the trick! Curious, how can I be certain that the `.change` event will always fire before the `.on` events?

Comment: You can't, I suppose. The code as is behaves like that, and I would be really surprised if it ever changed. If it did, the order of events would be 'selected' and then 'changed'. Weird to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few months old, but this is how you could do it:

Use jQuery to look at how many ".tt-suggestions" are in the DOM on each keyup event. If there are none, clear the hidden field.

```
$('.products_tt .typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'products_tt',
    prefetch: url: '/products.json',
    ttl: 60 * 5e3
    template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</p>',
    engine: Hogan
}).on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function (e, datum) {
    $('#disk_file_product_id').val(datum.id);
}).on('keyup', function () {
    if($('.tt-suggestion').length === 0){
        $('#disk_file_product_id').val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: This only applies to newer versions of the typeahead plugin. Older versions don't support named events.